The nilradical $\mathcal{N}(A)$ of $A$ is the intersection of all prime ideals of $A$.
I read the following proof in the book commutative algebra, Andrea Ferreri:
Proposition 1.6.10. The nilradical $\mathcal{N}(A)$ of $A$ is the intersection of all prime ideals of $A$.
Proof: Let $P$ be a prime ideal and let $a \in \mathcal{N}(A)$, then some power $a^n=$ $0 \in P$, so $a \in P$. This proves one inclusion.
For the other, let $a$ be contained in every prime ideal. Then $A_a$ is ring without prime ideals, that is, $A_a$ must be the $0$ ring. (Why?) Then $\iota(1)=0$ means that $1 \cdot a^n=0$ for some $n$, so $a$ is nilpotent.
I don't understand, why the localization of the ring has no prime ideals, and why should that imply that it is the ring $0$?

(1) Do you know how to describe the prime ideals in the localization $S^{-1}A$? They're in bijection with prime ideals in $A$ which are disjoint from $S$... (2) Do you know that every non-zero ring has at least one prime ideal? Use Zorn's Lemma to obtain a maximal ideal, which is prime...

If $A$ is a commutative ring and $a \in A$ lies in every prime ideal of $A$, then if you localise $A$ at the multiplicatively closed set $\{a^n: n \in \mathbb Z_{\geq 0}\}$ the ring $A_a$ you obtain has a natural map $\iota \colon A \to A_a$ and $\iota(a)$ is a unit in $A_a$ by construction.
Now if $\mathfrak p$ is a prime ideal in $A_a$, then $\mathfrak q :=\iota^{-1}(\mathfrak p)$ is a prime ideal in $A$: if $x,y \in A$ and $xy \in \mathfrak q$ then $\iota(xy) \in \mathfrak p$ hence $\iota(x)$ or $\iota(y)$ lie in $\mathfrak p$ so that $x$ or $y$ lie in $\mathfrak q$. But if $\mathfrak q$ is a prime ideal in $A$, then $a \in \mathfrak q$ and hence $\iota(a)/a \in \mathfrak p$ so that $\mathfrak p = A_a$. It follows that $A_a$ has no prime ideals.
If a ring has no prime ideals then it has, in particular, no maximal ideals. Since any nontrivial ring contains a maximal ideal by Zorn's Lemma, it follows that $A_a = \{0\}$ is the zero ring, and hence $\iota(1)=0$, so that $1.a^n=0$ for some $n>0$, that is, $a$ is nilpotent as required.

Please avoid posting answers to duplicate questions.

The question cited does not answer the question asked by the OP here. In my experience questions it is not as uncommon as I would like that questions are closed and declared duplicate to a question where that is simply not the case.

Why doesn't it answer the question? In any case, there are lot of related duplicates. Generally speaking, please add them to the list of duplicates instead of answering the same question that has been already asked >10 times on this site.

The question here asks about a particular framing of the proof that if $R$ is a commutative ring, then the intersection of all prime ideals in $R$ is precisely the ideal of nilpotent elements in $R$. In the question linked, the OP asks about how one shows that, if $x\in R$ is not nilpotent, then there is an prime ideal $\mathfrak p_x$ such that $x \notin \mathfrak p_x$. Eric's answer frames the argument in terms of localization but runs it in the same way as the explicit version of the argument.

The argument as given in the OP here takes the localisation approach but does not use the contrapositive -- it simply supposes the $a$ lies in all prime ideals of $R$ and inverts the set of its powers. The natural homomorphism from a ring to its localization, like any ring homomorphism, pulls-back prime ideals in $R_a$ to prime ideals in $R$, and hence any prime ideal in must contain a unit, which is a contradiction, so $R_a$ has no prime, and hence no maximal, ideals. Zorn's Lemma the shows this forces $R_a$ to be the zero ring, and hence $a$ to be nilpotent.

Now the content of all of these proofs is identical, but the framings are different. I don't see why the framing here, for someone just learning these ideas, would necessarily be transparently identifiable with those in the linked question.

Suppose that $\mathfrak p$ is a prime ideal of $A_a$, then the inverse image of $\mathfrak p$ is prime in $A$, but this contains $a$ by hypothesis so $a/1$ is in $\mathfrak p$. It follows that $\mathfrak p=A_a$ and is thus not prime, so no prime ideal can exist.
No prime ideals means no maximal ideals, but every nonzero ring has a maximal ideal by Zorn’s lemma so $A_a$ must be zero.

@AnneBauval thanks for the catch! Am on my phone so didn't catch those.

I wonder how this answer helps, 11 min after the more detailed one.

$a/a$ is in $\mathfrak p$ (like in the former answer) would be a clearer argument for $\mathfrak p=A_a$.

@AnneBauval I think my argument is plenty clear.

Please avoid posting answers to duplicate questions.
